# Why does GetFileAttributesW(L"C:") return FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, boost

Normally, `GetFileAttributesW(L"C:")` returns `0x10` (`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`), which is reasonable.

In some case, `GetFileAttributesW(L"C:")` will return `0x2416` (`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED`)

I wonder what makes it happen and how to get rid of it. This issue makes `boost::filesystem::canonical` can't work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: That looks perfectly reasonable to me. Why do you think that GetFileAttributesW is defective?

Comment: `C:` is not the same as `C:\\`. It is the current working directory which may change depending on your programme.

Comment: @RichardCritten Do you mean "C:" refers to "current working directory", which is very different from my original thought. Could you give me anything  to prove it ?

Comment: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable thank you, Richard you are right :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It looks like a mount point is reparse point, you are right. thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main confusion here is what `C:` means. This is interpreted as being the current directory on the `C` drive. This is explained over on MSDN: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths).

> If a file name begins with only a disk designator but not the
>   backslash after the colon, it is interpreted as a relative path to the
>   current directory on the drive with the specified letter. Note that
>   the current directory may or may not be the root directory depending
>   on what it was set to during the most recent "change directory"
>   operation on that disk. Examples of this format are as follows:
>
> - "C:tmp.txt" refers to a file named "tmp.txt" in the current directory on drive C.
> - "C:tempdir\tmp.txt" refers to a file in a subdirectory to the current directory on drive C.

So the value returned by `GetFileAttributesW(L"C:")` depends on what the current directory is. I believe that you are intending to obtain the attributes of the root folder, in which case you must use `GetFileAttributesW(L"C:\\")`.